# how to remove modem+manager+gui completely?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I have uninstalled modem+manager+gui through terminal still I can see error of modem-manager-gui while doing `apt-get update`

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxonly/modem+manager+gui/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

How can i remove it and can run `sudo apt-get update` without any error?

Answer (score 1):

During installation, you might have added ppa by running this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxonly/modem+manager+gui
```

You might have uninstall package `modem-manager-gui` but ppa is not removed.
So you need remove ppa `linuxonly/modem+manager+gui`

There will be a line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder like `linuxonly-ubuntu-modem_manager_gui-xenial.list`.

You need to remove that line and you can do this manually by running these commands:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo rm linuxonly-ubuntu-modem_manager_gui-xenial.list
```

OR

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:linuxonly/modem+manager+gui
```

After then you can do `sudo apt-get update` without any error.

For more information: [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed#310)

Comment: You can also simply run `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:linuxonly/modem+manager+gui` if it has been added using that same tool.

Comment: @ByteCommander One thing i noticed if i run this command, why `.list` file is not removed from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` automatically ?

Comment: The file is not removed, but empty afterwards IIRC, so it has no effect. Probably this is to make sure it doesn't remove anything else that could be in the file, like other repositories or comments...